# URL to custom object home page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, urlhacking, lightningnavigation

There are two object case and escalation_on_hold__c in case object lightning component i have created a form with case fields and when the button click it will show popup message and in that i have to show
url :- please go here if i click the url it have to go to custom object home page (escalation_on_hold__c)

I have created form with aura component using quick action am struggling with the URL

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is it in aura?

Comment: yes i have tried with ,

Comment: anchor tag  href

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer we can use force:navigationtohomepage in javascript and in component we can use lightning:navigation